# How do I run individual tests on Rails 5 with ruby-test on Atom

Tags: ruby, testing, atom-editor

When I left my company I also lost my license to RubyMine so I started working with Atom.  One feature I really missed from RubyMine was the ability to run individual tests directly from the editor.

After poking around a bit I found a library for Atom that accomplished this: https://atom.io/packages/ruby-test

This package is great, except I found that whenever I ran a test that had spaces in the name, the test wouldn't actually run.

How can I get the package to run tests that have spaces in their name?

Answer (score 0):

The command the package was using was:

```
ruby -I test {relative_path} -n "/{regex}/"
```

If you go into the settings, you can modify this to use `TESTOPTS` which supports spaces in the names:

```
ruby -I test {relative_path} TESTOPTS="-n /{regex}/"
```